# Using Web.config app data in Javascript/HTML

Tags: javascript, html, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am using [this tutorial](http://goo.gl/cSoZE) to use a variable from web.config file into .NET . Now I want to use the exact same variable in JavaScript but according to my research the  `WebConfigurationManager` variable is not available in HTML , any clue on how to do that ?

thanks

EDIT :

I tried to implement the suggested code in that way (just to make sure that it gives me the output I want):

```
var myJsVar = '<%= ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["MyConfigValue"] %>';
alert(myJsVar);
```

the value of `myJsVar` come  up as

```
<%= ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["MyConfigValue"] %>
```

and when I do '<%= ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["MyConfigValue"] %>'

and when I do `alert(myJsVar.valueof());` instead I receive `undefined` as output

I also tried to use `WebConfigurationManager` instead of `ConfigurationSettings` and it goes through the same logic ...

Comment: What version of asp.net are you using?

Comment: I am new to all this ... can it be IIS7 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can render the value to the aspx page, as an assignment to a JavaScript variable:

```
var myJsVar = '<%= ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["MyConfigValue"] %>';
```

So this way, `myJsVar` will be initialized with `MyConfigValue`. Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

If you are using Razor you should use this way

```
var myJsVar = '@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyConfigValue"]';
```

Comment: : thanks for your answer , I ran into some issues , can you please check the modifications to my question ?

Comment: are you sure that your page is an aspx page? or is an HTML page?

Comment: and I need this part in javascript

Comment: You are using Razor (that's an important difference). I've updated the post for using app settings using cshtml pages.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to output the setting into the variable you want. Somewhere in your javascript you would put:

```
<script language="javascript">

    var mySetting = '<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mySetting"] %>';

</script>
```

Here the `<%=` is a `Response.Write` command that will output the string result to the markup rendered. From this point on the variable `mySetting` would be accessible to any components.

Comment: @JoelEtheron : thanks for your answer , I ran into some issues , can you please check the modifications to my question ?